# Would Lamia Keep Themselves In Check Through Intraspecies Conflict

Tags: fantasy-races

After posting my last question ([How Can Lamia Survive In Alendyias?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/193799/how-can-lamia-survive-in-alendyias)), I seriously considered nerfing them, until I realized something: if humans are (arguably) our own worst enemy, would the same be true for my Lamia?

I'm picturing my Lamia as being opportunistic and manipulative, yet social-think the 'mean girls' in middle- or high-school literature, or perhaps drama-heavy TV shows (most of which are meant for girls...hm.....). In other words, they'll form cliques and pecking orders, with ruthless political maneuvers used to punish the opposition and climb up the ladder.

Lamia prefer not to eliminate (assassinate or otherwise engineer the demise of) their political opponents or those in a position they crave; they prefer to subjugate them instead because then the victim will have to suffer being demoted and under the usurper's authority while the usurper gets an emotional high from 'conquering' another Lamia.

Additionally, Lamia are capable of parthogenesis (birthing clones) and often have their own small army of subservient 'children.' So, my question is: *Would Lamia Keep Themselves In Check Through Intraspecies Conflict?*

*Consider:*

1. While Lamia are immune to their own 'spitfire' attacks, hypnotic abilities, and all acid and poison, they *aren't* immune to dominative vampirism; if a Lamia latches onto and *completely* exchanges blood with another Lamia (one fang drains the victim's blood, the other expels the attacker's blood) that Lamia becomes their thrall. If they don't manage to completely exchange blood, the control they have over the victim is determined by how much blood was exchanged.
2. If a Lamia is cut in half, she automatically becomes vulnerable; the upper half becomes a woman, the lower half becomes a large snake, both telepathically linked. The Lamia can restore herself by consuming her serpent half, but if another Lamia consumes it, that Lamia will gain the victim's power and the victim will be drawn to and absorbed by the consumer.
   This is high-risk, however, because the inverse occurs if a Lamia's serpent half consumes another Lamia.
   If a Lamia absorbs two other Lamia in this way, she becomes a Maralith (a six-armed, larger Lamia) and gains the ability to telepathically communicate with and compel other Lamia.
3. I assume 1 and 2 will keep Lamia distrustful of each other, and maybe even prevent them from forming society. If I'm wrong, or if I'm right, please inform me. As always, I appreciate your input!

Comment: do you mean *intra*species conflict?

Comment: Armor and you don't get cut in half....have a pocketful of cyanide with you all the time and no one will eat you... And if they do, they die.

Comment: See under 1; Lamia are immune to "all acid and poison," making cyanide useless. Also, you can't wear armor all the time.

Comment: Wowie, if the enthralling process come from giving out the dominator's blood to the dominated, and if the two have dominator's blood, we may fall into a funny paradox :p. Who's the dominated and the dominator x)? Do they have a sudden surge of dependency to each other? It's just a side note!

Comment: Interesting side note, Tortliena. What do you mean by dependency?

Comment: @Alendyias Well, it depends on how your enthralling magic works. I kinda see it personally like an über-love spell with a spark of bound-by-blood sisterhood, only platonic unless the two are actually physically attracted to each other, in which case... Well, you gotta fulfill the other deepest wishes! (NB: Don't forget to notify the person -@personName- especially when not commenting on their post, otherwise they might miss out your call :) ).

Comment: OK, thank you. I see it differently, but a 'bound-by-blood sisterhood' is an interesting idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These threats from other members of their own kind don't seem that much different from how humans are threatened by other humans, and we formed social groups just fine. In nature, just about every species is its own worst enemy, especially in social situations where fights over dominance hierarchies are a big deal. Bovids use their horns and baboons use their teeth more on each other than they do on any predator.

The biggest difference is going to be with parthenogenesis there will be less need for cooperation because a lamia can just birth an army of supporters. Why trust a stranger when you can just give birth to a brainwashed thrall that can't betray you? But even then it probably wouldn't prevent societies from forming.

Comment: I assume you know what you're talking about; but the way I see it, Lamia will naturally distrust and seek dominion over other Lamia; if they form societies, they'll have to account for the fact that another Lamia might drain their blood while they sleep and make them a thrall, or cut them in half so they can absorb them.

Comment: In other words, I need more evidence of how you know Lamia will form social groups despite the threat from each other.

Comment: @Alendyias Meanwhile, in lamia-verse Worldbuilding SE..."The way I see it, humans will naturally distrust and seek dominion over other humans. If they form societies they'll have to account for the fact that another human might cut their throat while they sleep, or poison them so they can inherit or steal their goods."

Comment: Ah, that settles it, your point is valid.